# how to choose serbain language from android Emulator settings?

Tags: android, emulation

friends,

i dont see serbain language in android phone language settings....
i am using honeyComb 3.0 and android does have serbain language support in this api.

any one guide me what mistake am i doing? and how to change phone language to serbain language?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to manage multiple languages from your own application you need to force localization in your application here is the example.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210127121431/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/force-localize-application-on-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi well i think want you want to do is here.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0.html#locs

if read at the end says Note: The Android platform may support more locales than are included in the SDK system image. All of the supported locales are available in the http://source.android.com/index.html

Hope it helped :S

Comment: the more strange thing is that it says it suports Serbian (sr_RS)

Comment: i know android supports but my question is related to how to test it in android emulator if it was french, italian and other common language then i could test it by changing android emulator language from settings but in current situation i dont see such kind of language in my emulator.