# Is NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance() failing to return right symbol in some countries?

Tags: android

I develop finance app that should use different currency symbol which depends on the country. I'm using this code:

```
Float value = 100;
TextView tv = (TextView) view;
NumberFormat currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
tv.setText(currencyFormat.format(value));
```

I have several reports that my app is returning Euro symbol instead the right currency (in Malysia or India for example). Those users state that their system language is native to their country. I can't prove that myself because there are no such languages avalaible on my phone or emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could try and force a locale in your app since this seems to be related to how the default locale is being set on the device. See these links -

[how to choose serbain language from android Emulator settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664361/how-to-choose-serbain-language-from-android-emulator-settings)

https://web.archive.org/web/20210127121431/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/force-localize-application-on-android.html

This would probably help you replicate the issue that users reported on their devices.

**EDIT:**
I have not tested this myself but it could work in your case.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String languageToLoad  = "en";
    String countryToLoad = "MY"; // 2 digit country code for Malaysia
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad, countryToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Locale list on the documentation is very poor http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html There is no Malesia at all, and my customer states that he has Malesian locale

Comment: I have not really worked with Locale all that much but check my edit. The Locale documentation does say that the available list varies based on the device itself.

Comment: It is mentioned in the Locale documentation. There are the two links for language and country code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3